# PouchDB Storage Limit - Firefox

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I'm trying to find the storage limits of PouchDB (using IndexDB) and having Problems with Firefox.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria the storage should be: "The global limit is calculated as 50% of free disk space" "There's also another limit called group limit — this is defined as 20% of the global limit". Therefore, if all local and index storage is deleted, I should be able to access 20% * 50% = 10% of the free Storage.

Am I missing something? On Chrome I'm able to access 11,20% on Firefox, using the same script, only 1,44%. I'm using an Angular2 app and the following javascript code for interfaceing pouchDb:

Creating Pouchdb:

```
function CreatePouchDB() {
  db = new PouchDB('pictures');
  console.log(db.adapter);
}
```

Adding 100 Entries (_content is a 1024KB, completly random, string):

```
function AddBunch100(_content) {
  var docs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100;  i++) {
    var doc = {
      _id: (id++).toString(),
      content: _content
    };

    docs.push(doc);
  }

  db.bulkDocs(docs)
    .then (function (response) {
      console.log('Done Adding 100 more');
      highestAddedId += 100;
    })
    .catch (function (err) {
      console.log("Some Error Occured: " + err);
      console.log('highest Added Id: ' + highestAddedId);
    });
};
```

My exact Measurements on the Topic are:

- Storage                                = 232GB (SSD)
- Free Storage                           = 133GB (SSD)
- used up Space on File System, Chrome   = 14,9GB
- used up Space on File System, Firefox  = 1,92GB
- Highest Added ID (code var), Chrome    = 8100 ~ 14.7 - 14.9GB (string
  is + 1.81MB in javascript)
- Highest Added ID (code var), Firefox   = 1500 ~ 2.7 - 2.9GB, I just realized that the calculated storage is bigger than what i can see on the file system, am i looking in the wrong place?

Trying to figure this out for a while now, any help would be appreciated.
The paths i used are:

- Chrome  = *USER*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB
- Firefox = *USER*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\dicb2x96.default\storage\default

---

Edit:
Ok, seems like I made a mistake: I don't know why yet but storing the data into the default storage of Firefox limited me to 2Gb (For me at least). I just tried storing into the persitent storage by changing CreatePouchDB to db = new PouchDB('pictures', {storage:'persistent'}); and I'm currently storing 18.9GB of data (which now is more than the 10%) and growing.

---

Edit:
Final Values Firefox:

- used up Space on File System, Firefox = 25GB
- Highest Added ID (code var), Firefox = 20000 ~ 36.3 - 36.4GB, Still
  bigger than what can be seen on the file System.